# Programmatically turn off the system sound for NFC proximity on Windows 10 phone

Tags: win-universal-app, nfc, windows-10-mobile, template10

I'm developing a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app for use on Windows 10 phones (e.g., Lumia 950/950XL). Part of the app requires that an NFC tag is tapped to allow the user to indicate their presence at a particular location.

When the phone comes into range of a tag, a system generated sound plays. This is independent of the app. I'd like to be able to turn this sound off, because when the tag is tapped, I want to indicate success or failure by my own sounds. The system sound is quite long, and as far as I can see there's no way to change it.

Is there any way to turn off the system sound from within the app?

Comment: No, there is no way to change any system sound and even volume level.

Comment: @khamitimur - you **can** change the volume of the sound by turning down the "ringer + notifications" volume, using the phone's volume keys. So turning it right the way down to vibrate, while leaving the "media + apps" volume up, will stop it making the system sound, but allow the sound from the app to play. However, that doesn't really answer the question as that would leave the user without an audible ringtone.

Comment: I meant no way to do that with API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, the Universal Windows Platform cannot change system settings for the user. There are, of course, operating system API used by the Windows Settings apps, but those are not public and have not been announced to be made so. This includes sounds. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I suspected this might be the case.